# spring-data cassandra search on more than one key

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data

I am trying to search a table with multiple composite keys using spring-data Cassandra.

my table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id1 text,
    id2 text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
```

My repository looks like this

```
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository <Test, String> {
  public List<Message> findById1(String id1);
}
```

This works fine, but now I need to search when I have id1 and also id2.

### Things I have tried

This does not compile, it gives me an error

```
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository <Test, String> {
  public List<Message> findById1(String id1);
  public List<Message> findById1Id2(String id1, String id2);
}
```

**Error**

```
 No property id2 found for type String! Traversed path: Message.id2.
```

This compiles but it says I need to allow filtering, obviously because I didn't provide the first primary key.

```
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository <Test, String> {
  public List<Message> findById1(String id1);
  public List<Message> findById2(String id1, String id2);
}
```

**Error**

```
 Error about Allow Filtering.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the **and** between the `findById1Id2` should be `findById1AndId2`. The repo looks like this

```
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository <Test, String> {
  public List<Message> findById1AndId2(String id1, String id2);
}
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/)

> 7.4.2. Query creation
>
> ....
>
> At a very basic level you can define
>   conditions on entity properties and concatenate them with And and Or.

#### NOTE

I answered instead of deleting the question because I could not find any information on StackOverflow.

Comment: but how can you do a public List<Message> findById1(String id1); without the "allow filtering" error?